# Using SAML and https or http

Tags: http, https, saml

I am working on an service which provides authentication service using SAML SSO protocol for communication security.

Brief Intro :- SAML SSO recognizes Identity Provider (IP or IDP) and Service Provider, which “trusts” and delegates user authentication to IDP. Here is how trust is established:
1. Service Provider (SP):
    - trusted IDP name and certificate
    - single sign on (SSO) URL
  2. Identity Provider (IDP):
    - relying SP name and certificate
    - SSO consumer URL
Whenever SP needs to authenticate user, it redirects it to SSO endpoint and passes SAMLRequest wither in query string or form field (GET or POST method).

What I would like to know is that is it a requirement that the client who requires authentication should be sending request through "https" protocol or the request can also be relayed across using http channel. I am just asking is the SAML protocol mandates us to use https or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SAML does not require the use of HTTPS. But you should protect your messages in some way. This might be by using XML signature/encryption, HTTPS or some other way. HTTPS will probably be the easiest way to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

SAML does not **REQUIRE** the use of HTTPS, but it is **RECOMMENDED**.

It's an authentication mechanism (even if we're only talking the AuthnRequest), so my question back would be why *wouldn't* you use HTTPS?